# Asus Zenfone 3 Max - ZC520TL - Cant boot anymore - Only fastboot

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, bootloader

I have a Asus Zenfone 3 Max, ZC520TL, MT6737M WWW_phone X008_1, 7.0/NRD 90M 14.10.1808.119-2018

I wanted to install lineage on my phone without rooting it (I want to be able to use banking app), I took a look on internet on how to do it and the first step was unloacking the bootloader and then installing twrp

With the apk on the asus website, I unlocked the bootloader, then I rebooted to it in fastboot mode
I tried to install twrp from different sources I could find on internet (my phone is not officially supported by TWRP) with "fastboot flash recovery IMAGE.img"

None of these images worked

I did few tries with these commands (in this order) :

```
fastboot erase cache
fastboot flash boot recovery.img
fastboot erase recovery
```

And then the problems began...
I can't access the recovery mode, it displays in the background the asus logo and then reboot;
I can't access the normal boot, it's looping;
I only have access to the fastboot mode

So from now, I wanted to make my phone works again, I tried to flash both in boot and recovery partitions the boot.img extracted from the official rom available on the asus website
Tried to reinstall the unsuccesful TWRP img I already downloaded
And my phone doesn't support "fastboot boot IMAGE.img"

Does anyone have an idea on how to make it works?

Thank you

Comment: `fastboot erase` will erase partitions, that makes device unbootable (besides your other mistakes and dm-verity) stock recovery.img should flashed to recovery partition, stock boot.img must flashed to boot partition, and `fastboot format:ext4 cache` will create new cache partition

Comment: I did the cache format, however I successfully wrote the boot.img but nothing better

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/recovery-twrp-3-1-1-asus-zenfon-3-max-t3650670

Comment: there are different MT6737T and MT6737M

Comment: I went through this page, the problem is I am on Linux, and the 3 TWRP images they gave are written successfully but do not work

Comment: How can I know which MT6737M I am using?
Is there a version to select for no-verity-opt-encrypt.zip?

Comment: I flashed the boot.img of the correct version, after checking it I was using the 15.10 instead of 14.10, so now it boot correctly to install the os but still no recovery, how can I get it?

Comment: version of no-verity-opt-encrypt doesn't matter. are you sure twrp is not working? sounds more like TWRP is replaced with stock recovery on each boot. check your hardware matches the TWRP build. get device info with this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.andr7e.deviceinfohw